# 307 Temporary redirect message in Jmeter,

Tags: performance, jmeter, http-status-code-307

I am trying to do a performance test for an application in which when the user hits the login URL with Credentials, it redirects to another URL and proceeds so on.

I checked the Csrf token supplied to the Url and it is correct. I also checked the user credentials supplied in header data and it is also correct. I even checked for session id and it is static till the redirection happens. I unable to extract a token for active session since the redirection happens with error. can someone help with what is wrong in this scenarios.

Tried with Follow redirects option and getting the below error.. when tried with automatically redirect no error found but invalid session response was shown.

Request:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdNVZ.png)

Response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72SdI.png)

Answer (score 1):

As per [307 Temporary Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) status description:

> [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTP) `307 Temporary Redirect` redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) headers.

JMeter should follow the redirect and make the request to the target URL, if it doesn't - play with `Redirect automatically` and `Follow redirects` boxes:

[image]

In any case you should be able to extract the target URL from the Location header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor) and put the resulting URL into "Path" section of the next [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

Also JMeter should treat HTTP Status 307 as success (as well as any other HTTP status code below 400) so maybe you have an Assertion somewhere which artificially fails the Sampler based on the status code (i.e. checking if it's equal to `200`)